# Best approach to join selects and setup a column value in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, select

I have the following queries

DECLARE @Selected bit
    Set @Selected = 0

```
SELECT CAST (ms.sector_id as int) as Id
,CAST (s.parent_sector_id as int) as ParentSectorID
,s.[name]  as Name
FROM matter_sector ms LEFT JOIN sector s ON ms.sector_id=s.sector_id 
WHERE ms.matter_number = '00597619' AND parent_sector_id = 0

SELECT CAST ([sector_id] AS int) AS Id
,CAST ([parent_sector_id] AS int) AS ParentSectorID
,[name] AS Name
,@Selected AS Selected
FROM sector
where parent_sector_id = 0
```

Here is the result

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to update the Selected value to 1 for the record with Id 596. The first select statement could return multiple records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST ([sector_id] AS int) AS Id
,CAST ([parent_sector_id] AS int) AS ParentSectorID
,[name] AS Name
,case sector_id when (SELECT CAST (ms.sector_id as int) as Id
FROM matter_sector ms LEFT JOIN sector s ON ms.sector_id=s.sector_id 
WHERE ms.matter_number = '00597619' AND parent_sector_id = 0) then 1 else 0 end as 'Selected'
FROM sector
where parent_sector_id = 0
```

Comment: This is close. Selected is not available in sector table. This is a parameter that I need to return in the select statement and it is declared inside the query

Comment: Whoops, I've revised it.